# bootstrap form-control plus form-control-user select option blank

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a CRUD with bootstrap. When I have a tag select I have a problem.

I have this situation below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1WTB.png

with the code:

```
          <div class="form-group row">
           <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">              
            <select class="form-control form-control-user" id="citizenship">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Citizenship</option>
                <option value="AU_Citizen">AU Citizen</option>
                <option value="NZ_Citizen">NZ Citizen</option>
                <option value="Other">Other*</option> 
            </select>    
          </div>
```

If I click on the select option, the field shows me all option that I have, but when I select one of them the field keep in the blank. However, if I use only form-control or form-control-user, it works, but without style. My problem is when I use both together.

The image below is using only form-control:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqcrR.png

The image below is using only form-control-user:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9v1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear @dtauil I Think may you have given a extra padding
- Give this CSS with respective class. you have to do a change in height don't change in padding. i have done change using your code **height: calc(2.9em + .75rem + 2px);**, 
  **border-radius: 50px;**

```
/*Use this css code*/ 

   .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(2.9em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hiren! First of all, thank you very much to reply to my post.
I did the changes but keep on the same stage. The option selected does not appear inside the field. =(

Comment: Hiren!!! I got it! in the padding line was 1.5rem, I changed to .3rem and it worked!

form.user .form-control-user {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  padding: .3rem 1rem; 
}

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your most welcome @dtauil, you can mark this question as accepted so it will be helpful for others who facing a same issue.